Exporting rotated map in GeoPDF (or any other way to exclude exported layers) with QGIS
I’m trying to export a rotated map I’ve created, but it seems I can’t do this as a GeoPDF. GeoPDF was convenient for selectively excluding unwanted layers and attributes, which kept the file size small (around 40MB). When I export as a regular PDF, the file size jumps to about 450MB.
Is there a way to control which layers and attributes are included in a regular PDF export? Or is there any workaround to export a rotated map as a GeoPDF? Unfortunately, exporting as SVG doesn’t work properly either.


Which QGIS version is that ?

You can't just turn off the unwanted layers prior to exporting to pdf?

QGIS version is 3.36.2-Maidenhead but I have tried with 3.34.13 Long-term version and the latest 3.40.1 and it is the same.
There is no option to turn off the unwanted layers prior to exporting if it's not a GeoPDF. Layers are not visible in the project, but I guess, according to the file size, everything gets exported.

Would your question be related to this project? This may be a solving for X, when you’re trying to solve for Y problem.
Edit: Add description for the XY Problem.

Yes, this is the project the question refers to. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Sure! I've added a link so things aren't so opaque.
